# Insert JSP data into MS Access database?

Tags: html, jsp, ms-access

I keep getting different errors while trying to insert data retrieved from a html page using JSP into a table in my MS Access database. Everyone time I try to fix or change my code I get a different error. the current error is:

(ps. i'm using apache tomcat. my database is called "tico" and "Contacts" is the name of the table. the field names in MS access are "Job Code:" and "TICo's Client:"). If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated. thanks. :)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
enter code here 

HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /TICo Website/onejsp.jsp     at line 21

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /TICo Website/onejsp.jsp at line 21

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling     this request.``

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /TICo Website/onejsp.jsp at line 21

 18:      url = "jdbc:odbc:tico" 
 19: />
 20: 
 21: <sql:update var="tico" scope="request" dataSource ="${tico}">
 22:  INSERT INTO Contacts
 23:  ([Job Code:], [TICo's Client:])
 24:  VALUES (?, ?)
```

---

```
                                                                                            Stacktrace:  
                                                                                             org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException

(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)        
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

 root cause

 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get   
  connection, 
   DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft]
   [ODBC Driver Manager]           
    Data source name not found and no default driver specified"     
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException
   (PageContextImpl.java:865)

   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException
  (PageContextImpl.java:794)
   org.apache.jsp.TICo_0020Website.onejsp_jsp._jspService(onejsp_jsp.java:215)
   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

   root cause

   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid:
   "java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name 
   not found and   no     default driver specified"
  org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.UpdateTagSupport.
  getConnection(UpdateTagSupport.   java:243)
 org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.UpdateTagSupport.doStartTag
 (UpdateTagSupport.jav     a:124)

 org.apache.jsp.TICo_0020Website.onejsp_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fupdate_005f0
 (onejsp_jsp.java:    264)

org.apache.jsp.TICo_0020Website.onejsp_jsp._jspService(onejsp_jsp.java:80)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)    

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache     
Tomcat/6.0.37     logs.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.37


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
full stack trace
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

enter code hereJun 25, 2013 9:54:33 AM   
org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener    init 

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance 

in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program 
 Files\Apache    Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:

\Windows    \system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32
 \Wbem;C:\Windows    \System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;.    

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:33 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init

INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 438 ms

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start

INFO: Starting service Catalina

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor

INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory docs

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:34 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start

INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:34 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init

INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:34 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start

INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null

Jun 25, 2013 9:54:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

 INFO: Server startup in 800 ms

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:14 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause

INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop

INFO: Stopping service Catalina

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:15 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy

INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init   

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance 

in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program 

Files\Apache   Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows  

\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:
\Windows   \System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;.   

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:21 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init

INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 348 ms

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start

INFO: Starting service Catalina

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor

INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory docs

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:22 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start

INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:22 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init

INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:22 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start

INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null

Jun 25, 2013 10:03:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in 495 ms`
```

---

### JSP Page

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Using GET and POST Method to Read Form Data</title>
</head>
<body>                  

<sql:setDataSource
    var = "tico" 
    scope = "session" 
    driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
    url = "jdbc:odbc:tico" 
 />

 <sql:update var="tico" scope="request" dataSource ="${tico}">
 INSERT INTO Contacts
 (Job Code:, TICo's Client:)
 VALUES (?, ?)
 <sql:param value = "${param.jobcode}" />
 <sql:param value = "${param.ticosclient}" />
 </sql:update>  

 <center>
 <h1>Using GET Method to Read Form Data</h1>
 <div style="position:absolute; top:20px; width:100%; height:80px;">
 <ul>
 <table align='center' style="width: 1000px; height: 81px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" 
  cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <col width="33">
  <col width="33">
   <col width="33">
   <col width="33"></br></br></br>

<tr><td>     
<li><p><b>Job Code:</b>
   <%= request.getParameter("jobcode")%>
</p></li>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>
<li><p><b>TICo's Client:</b>
   <%= request.getParameter("ticosclient")%>
</p></li>
</td></tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace please?

Comment: Hi Jack. By full stack trace, do you mean the entire error page that apache Tomcat gives , when my code has an error???

Comment: @Jack Harkness .Hi Jack, I added the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly one thing you'll need to fix is your SQL command text.

```
INSERT INTO Contacts
(Job Code:, TICo's Client:)
VALUES (?, ?)
```

will have to be changed to

```
INSERT INTO Contacts
([Job Code:], [TICo's Client:])
VALUES (?, ?)
```

By the way, you may want to double-check that there really are colon (`:`) characters in the field names. That's quite normal for labels on a form, but it's rather unusual for them to be included in the actual field names.

### Edit

The "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" error suggests that the JSP process is running in the 64-bit environment and the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE") has not been installed on the server. To correct that, download and install the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255), then create a 64-bit System DSN for the database (via the normal Windows Control Panel applet, not SYSWOW64).

Comment: Thank You Gord, I will try that. I included the colon in the field names in MS Access. I might remove them though just incase.

Comment: .Hi Gord, I made the changes you suggested, but im still getting the same error "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /TICo Website/onejsp.jsp at line 21". Anything else you can see that could cause this. Please.

Comment: @ConorCaslin It looks like you are using an ODBC DSN named `tico` to connect to the database. If so, is it defined as a "System DSN" in `Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC)`?

Comment: .Thank you for getting back to us Gord. It wasn't originally, but i came across that suggestion while googling the error. also came a across this. "To manage a data source that connects to a 32-bit driver under 64-bit platform, use c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. To manage a data source that connects to a 64-bit driver, use c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe." i have been using the sysWOW64 path, because that is the only one where i can add a microsoft access driver.

Comment: I have installed the program you provided a link for. when i try to create a system DSN. Their is no Microsoft access provided in the options like sysWOW64. How do i connect my JSP page to MS Access, if the option is not available via "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Data Sourcs(ODBC)". Thank You.

Comment: just realised there that the link provided two exe's. One of them won't let me install the program, and gives me the warning "You cannot install 64-bit version of microsoft access database engine 2010 because you currently have 32-bit office products installed".

Comment: @ConorCaslin Okay, in that case you'll probably need to either (1) get your JSP server to run as 32-bit, or (2) switch to using 64-bit Office applications.

Comment: Thanks Gord for all your help and time. I actually started the process of switching to 64-bit office applications. I uninstalled my microsoft office program and installed the programs you supplied me with in your last comment. now i'm having trouble installing microsoft office 64 bit. when i run the setup.exe for microsoft office 64 bit, im getting an error "F:\ProPlus.\WW\OSETUP.DLL digital signature does not validate or is not present.".  would changing the JSP server to run as 32 be easier?, and how do you go about doing it?. Thanks

Comment: also getting this error from apache tomcat **"exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: General error"**. Starting to think ill never get this working. haha.

Comment: @ConorCaslin RE: Office install issue - Some web references suggest that [this](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) might help correct the problem.

Comment: Hi Gord, Thanks. I have Microsoft office 64-bit installed now & also the Microsoft access database engine 2010. Have created a data source in data sources(ODBC) system DSN tab. unfortunately i have a new error now when i run my JSP with apache tomcat. **"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: General error".**

Comment: @ConorCaslin "Data Source invalid" sounds like the account under which Apache Tomcat runs is unable to access the database file (.accdb or .mdb). Can you confirm that the DSN is working correctly, for example by using it to pull some information into an Excel document?

Comment: Pull data from my MS access database to MS Excel?. not too sure how to do that. Might take us a few minutes.

Comment: @ConorCaslin In Excel, choose `Data > From Other Sources > From Microsoft Query` then choose your DSN from the list. (Using the direct `Data > From Access` option won't prove anything since it won't use the ODBC DSN.)

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. getting **"driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed"** error followed by **"Couldn't read this file"** error.

Comment: I can load other MS access databases though, but not the "tico" one Im using .

Comment: i deleted the "tico" DSN, and recreated it. It now loads in excel using the instructions previously posted.

Comment: @ Gord Thompson .                                               apache tomcat error has changed from **unable to get connection** to                                 **org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: INSERT INTO Contacts ([Job Code:], [TICo's Client:]) VALUES(?,?)                                                         : Unexpected exception : null org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrappe‌​r.java:502) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)**

Comment: error continues(couldn't fit it all in the last comment). **org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)**.